# Pull Arris SB8200 Cable Modem Status With Curl

Tags: authentication, curl

Short Version:

- I use Node-RED automation to manage network.
- Via Node-RED I query the Arris SB8200 Cable Modem to get connection and event status hourly and store in a database.
- A recent Comcast modem firmware update forces usage of user/pw on the modem to retrieve status.
- I have been unable to successfully authenticate and retrieve status via cURL but can do so from a browser.

I have googled and tried a dozen different cURL authentication approaches without success. There are 3 complicating factors:

1. Username/password authentication. I am assuming this is just basic auth and shouldn't be an issue but see #2.
2. There is a session cookie "credential" that must be maintained across requests. This shouldn't be a problem but no matter what I try no cookies are captured in my specified cookies.txt file.
3. A manual login (to https://192.168.100.1/) is immediately followed by a redirect (to https://192.168.100.1/cmconnectionstatus.html). When I try to use the chrome dev tools "save as cURL" only the redirect is available, not the initial login so I cannot capture the login cURL.

I am hoping somebody who reads this has cURL'd into an SB8200 cable modem (or similar) with user/pw authentication and can just post the details. More likely will be many suggestions of things to try and some google result links, most of which I likely tried already. What would be most helpful to start I think is troubleshooting why I cannot get a successful login and the credential cookie set on my initial cURL.

BTW - The username and password are known to me, were set by me, and work fine to login from a browser. I think no matter how I have passed in the credentials I am just being returned the login form again. Maybe basic auth will never work and I need to do something else.

EDIT: I discovered the "Preserve Log" option in Chrome dev tools. This allowed me to copy as curl both the login and the redirect actions. And running the login curl (which does use basic auth) does return me on stdout a credential cookie. I was not able to get this cookie stored in my cookies.txt file using the cookie options in curl. And immediately using the returned cookie in the redirect curl does not get me the expected results and instead returns the login page. But I am getting closer.

Here is the Chrome-captured cURL for the login and redirect from the browser:

```js
curl 'https://192.168.100.1/cmconnectionstatus.html?<REDACTED>' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'DNT: 1' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic <REDACTED>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Cookie: HttpOnly: true, Secure: true' \
  --compressed \
  --insecure

curl 'https://192.168.100.1/cmconnectionstatus.html' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'DNT: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Cookie: HttpOnly: true, Secure: true; credential=gmhyY4SjR3qiWBiNIOtivpj4TF5Zwad' \
  --compressed \
  --insecure
```

Here is the HTML document returned when I try to login:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="json2.js"></script>
<script src="main_arris.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#htmlheader").load("htmlheader.htm");
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="htmlheader"></div>
<div class="header">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pageheaderA").load("pageheaderA.htm"); 
});
</script>


         <div id="binnacleWrapper1" class="binnacleItems_hide" style="display:none;">
            <div id="binnacleWrapper2" class="binnacleItems_hide" style="display:none;">
                <div id="binnacleWrapperLeft"><img src="px1_Ux.png" alt="" class="binnacleWrapperShim"></div>
                <div id="binnacleWrapperRight"><img src="px1_Ux.png" alt="" class="binnacleWrapperShim"></div>
                <div id="binnacleWrapperMiddle">
                    <div id="binnacleInnards">
                        <div id="binnacleIndicatorWrap"></div>
                            <div id="binnacleModelName">
                             <span id="thisModelNumberIs">
                               <label id="model">SB8200</label></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div id="pageheaderA"></div>

        <div class="container">
                <div class="subHeader">
                        <div class="subHeadcontent">Login</div>
                </div>
        <form action="">
               <br>
               <b>Username:</b><br>
               <input type="text" id="username" onkeypress="return checkForActivate(event)">
               <br>
               <br>
               <b>Password:</b><br>
               <input type="password" id="password" onkeypress="return checkForActivate(event)">
               <br>
               <br>
               <input type="button" id="loginButton" onclick="validate(this.form)" value="Login">
        </form>
        </div>

<div class="spacer40" style="text-align: center; color: red; font-weight: bold;"></div>
<div class="spacer70"></div>

</div>
<!--gap<div id="bmtg"><div class="gap1"><div class="gap2"><div class="gap3"><div class="gap4"></div></div></div></div></div>-->

<div id="fg1"><div id="fg2"><div id="fg3"><div id="fg4"><div id="fg5"><div id="fg6"><div id="fg7">
   <div id="logo_bottom"><a href="http://www.arris.com"><img src="px1_Ux.png" alt="ARRIS" title="ARRIS" class="logo_bottom"></a></div>
   <div id="copyright">
      <a href="http://www.arris.com">&copy;CommScope, Inc. All rights reserved. ARRIS, SURFBOARD and SURFBOARD MAX are trademarks of CommScope, Inc.<br />All other trademarks are the property of their respective owners.</a>
   </div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<!--/div-->


<script>
function authenticateUser(user, password)
{
    var token = user + ":" + password;

    // Base64 Encoding -> btoa
    var hash = btoa(token); 

    var auth = hash;
    sessionStorage.setItem('auth', auth);
    return auth;
}

function validate( form )
{
        $(".spacer40")[0].innerHTML = "";
        authenticateUser(form.username.value, form.password.value);
        localStorage.setItem('username', form.username.value);
        eraseCookie("credential");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:"/cmconnectionstatus.html?" + sessionStorage.getItem('auth'),
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            xhrFields: {
               withCredentials: true
            },
            headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Basic ' + sessionStorage.getItem('auth')
            },
            success: function (result) {
               var token = result;
                createCookie("credential", result);
                window.location.href = "/cmconnectionstatus.html";
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(error);
            }
        });
}
   

function checkForActivate( e )
{
   if( e.keyCode == 13 )
   {
      document.getElementById("loginButton").click();
   }
   
   return true;
}
   
</script>

<!--/div-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. Once I was able to save the login as curl in chrome, things fell in place. Looks like I was missing some required curl options in my initial attempts. I still need to skinny this down to the minimal necessary options, eliminate the double copy of user/pw chrome encoded, and add error checking. But the following will successfully login and pull modem status for an Arris SB8200. Never did get curl to store the credential cookie in a cookies.txt file so just used a local shell variable.

```js
cookie=`curl 'https://192.168.100.1/cmconnectionstatus.html?<REDACTED>'   -H 'Connection: keep-alive'   -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"'   -H 'DNT: 1'   -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0'   -H 'Authorization: Basic <REDACTED>'   -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'   -H 'Accept: */*'   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36'   -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin'   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors'   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty'   -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9'   -H 'Cookie: HttpOnly: true, Secure: true'   --compressed   --insecure`

curl 'https://192.168.100.1/cmconnectionstatus.html'   -H 'Connection: keep-alive'   -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"'   -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0'   -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'   -H 'DNT: 1'   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36'   -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin'   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate'   -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1'   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document'   -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9'   -H 'Cookie: HttpOnly: true, Secure: true; credential='$cookie  --compressed   --insecure
```

Comment: Important Notes: The login authentication code in the SB8200 seems to have been hastily implemented as the result of security concerns over unauthenticated login. There seems to be a limit to the number of concurrent sessions permitted, a fixed item session table. After multiple concurrent unique login sessions, the SB8200 will stop accepting ANY logins until it is rebooted. It will return Invalid User/Password. The easiest solution for scripted access is to add the curl for logout so each session ends cleanly.

Comment: Nice write-up and solution. Could you clarify, what data / credentials are supposed to go in the spots you've labeled "REDACTED" in your script? The username & password to log in to the modem? Can you also provide a sample usage showing the exact syntax?